# Filter by using in for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below table

```
Col1       Col2
1          ACA,ABS,PHR
2          PHR
3          MCM
4          ABC
```

Now I want to filter the data from this so if I have a filter parameter as say `'ABS,MCM'` I want to get only the rows which have at least one matching code. So in this case I should get the filtered result as

```
Col1       Col2
1          ACA,ABS,PHR
2          MCM
```

Now I can use the query `Select * from myTable where Col2 in ('ABS','MCM')` but then it won't retrieve the first row `ACA,ABS,PHR`. Can some one please tell me how I can do a text search for codes so as long as one code matches in Col2 I get the row so I can pass in directly the , delimited list and as long as it finds a single match the row is retrieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also split the string and then search on the splitted values.
An example could be by creating and using [this function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/).

Starting from SQL Server 2016 you could use the built in `STRING_SPLIT()` function.

**Creating the function from the blogpost and executing this query afterwards**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1,Col2 
FROM dbo.Searching
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(col2,',')
WHERE splitdata in ('ABS','MCM');
```

**Result**

```
Col1    Col2
1   ACA,ABS,PHR
3   MCM
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=5cb25b1fbe4409a5f354a75b81defeae)

An optimization could be proactively splitting the table into a permanent one so you don't need to do splitting on the entire table everytime.  (If the values are static)

---

**EDIT**

Comment by @Erikdarling

> There are better ways to split strings: [Comparing string splitting /
>   concatenation methods](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/01/t-sql-queries/comparing-splitting-concat), including a much better one at [SSC by Jeff
>   Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

**The function by [Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)**

After creating the function in his blogpost, you could use a query that resembles the previous one.

```
  SELECT Col1,Col2
  FROM dbo.Searching
  CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8k(Col2,',') split
  WHERE split.Item in ('ABS','MCM');
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=deccb2259a556d8d281fcde5e1ca6433)

Answer (score 4):

When I see *filter parameter*, I think input parameter to a stored procedure, so nothing hardcoded in the actual query.  This is a twist on @Randi's version that uses an inline string splitter technique to split the incoming parameter into rows and using `CROSS APPLY` and `LIKE` to find matches.

```
--demo setup
declare @T table(col1 int, col2 varchar(100))
insert into @T(col1,col2) values
(1,'ACA,ABS,PHR'),
(2,'PHR'),
(3,'MCM'),
(4,'ABC')

--Declare the input parameter - passed into a stored procedure perhaps?
Declare @Parm varchar(100) = 'ABS,MCM'


--Common Table Expression - Inline string splitter, since you can't use STRING_SPLIT() from SQL 2016
;WITH SplitParms
AS (
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(8000)'))) AS Code
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(@Parm, ',', '</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
        ) t
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData') m(n)
    )
--use CROSS APPLY and LIKE to find matching rows
SELECT t.*
FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY SplitParms sp
WHERE t.col2 LIKE ('%' + sp.Code + '%')
```

---

```
| col1 | col2        |
|------|-------------|
| 1    | ACA,ABS,PHR |
| 3    | MCM         |
```

Answer (score 2):

The most correct solution is to normalize. You need to put the codes in another table with a foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE MyThings (
    Col1 IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    -- Other columns you already have on the table
    Col3 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Col4 DECIMAL NOT NULL
);

-- Probably needs some kind of primary key.
CREATE TABLE MyThingCodes (
    Col1 NOT NULL REFERENCES MyThings (Col1),
    Code VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

And we can index it (since the codes are short) to speed up these queries:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_MyThingCodes_Code ON MyThingCodes (Code);
```

Then you can use an `EXISTS` query to find rows that match the code:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyThings
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM MyThingCodes
    WHERE
        MyThingCodes.Col1 = MyThings.Col1
        AND MyThingCodes.Code IN ('ABS','MCM')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use like. 
`where col2 like '%ABS%' or col2 like '%MCM%'`

Comment: Agreed that this will work, but I cannot help but feel that there must be an easier/more dynamic way of doing this.

Comment: @WadeH It depends on the codes. It will fail if `LABST` is also a code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.  I don't have a large enough dataset to show performance gains either way, but one option (my Attempt 1) splits the string you are searching rather than the entire table.  Of course, unbound string searches may be more costly than you want to pay, but you can do testing to show.  Alternatively, in Attempt 3, I show how you can do it without using a string of OR clauses or string_split.

```
/** BUILD UP DATA */
DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(100) = 'ABS,MCM'

DECLARE @Test TABLE
    (
    Col1 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
    , Col2 VARCHAR(100) NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @Test
(Col2)
VALUES ('ACA,ABS PHR')
    , ('PHR')
    , ('MCM')
    , ('ABC')
    , ('ABS,MCM')   --Included to demonstrate if one record has multiple code matches.

/** ATTEMPT 1 - UNBOUNDED WILDCARD SEARCH
    - Still uses STRING_SPLIT, just on the Search String rather than the main table.
    */
;WITH CTE_Distinct AS
    (
    SELECT T.*
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Col1 ORDER BY T.Col1)
    FROM @Test AS T
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@SearchString, ',') AS V 
    WHERE T.Col2 LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(V.value)) + '%'
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE_Distinct WHERE RN = 1

/** ATTEMPT 2 - DIRECT QUERY, 
    but uses STRING_SPLIT on the Col2
    */
;WITH CTE_Distinct AS
    (
    SELECT T.*
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Col1 ORDER BY T.Col1)
    FROM @Test AS T
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(T.Col2, ',') AS V 
    WHERE V.value IN ('ABS', 'MCM')
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE_Distinct WHERE RN = 1

/** ATTEMPT 3 - UNBOUND WILDCARD, but no string splitting required.  
    */
DECLARE @SearchTable TABLE
    (
    Code VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @SearchTable
(Code)
VALUES ('ABS')
    , ('MCM')

;WITH CTE_Distinct AS
    (
    SELECT T.*
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Col1 ORDER BY T.Col1)
    FROM @Test AS T
        INNER JOIN @SearchTable AS P ON T.Col2 LIKE '%' + P.Code + '%'
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE_Distinct WHERE RN = 1
```